# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'med' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function:

```
def compute():
    if txtot.get() == "":
        ot = 0
    elif txtmed.get() == "":
        med = 0
    else:
        bon = 0

    total = ot+med+bon
    print ("",total)
```

Which when called raises:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'med' referenced before assignment
```

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: As written only one of those variables will ever exist at a time, you will never have all three at the same time. I'd suggest you initialize the variables at the beginning of your `compute` function before your `if` statements.

Comment: @CoryKramer how to initialize the variables . im just new in python

Comment: Then see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F; that's covered in any basic tutorial.

Comment: You... initialize them. Assign them values before the `if` statement.

Comment: idontknow how to initialize a variable im pretty new in python language. im sorry

Comment: You are already doing it here `bon = 0` just do that before the if with some default value.

Comment: ahhh okay i get it. thank for the help guys. sorry for my question i know its pretty common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only one of the branches of your `if-elif-else` statement will be executed, variables that are not assigned a value in *all three* of the branch will always have a way not to exist after the if-statement.

In that case, your output will always be `0`, but in general you would want your variables to be initialized to some value before the if-statement and increment them based on the condition.

```
def compute():
    ot = med = bon = 0

    if txtot.get() == "":
        ot += 1
    elif txtmed.get() == "":
        med += 2
    else:
        bon += 3

    total = ot + med + bon
    print (total)
```